# Specifying number of samples for a custom xaudio2 effect

Tags: fft, xaudio2

I'm trying to write a custom xaudio2 effect that involves a fourier transform. However, the number of samples given to the process method each call is not a power of 2 (a precondition of the fourier transform implementation I have).

Is there a way to force power of 2 sized samples? Is there a technique to allow working with non power of 2 sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send samples to the FFT every call that you are given samples.  Buffer (save) them up till you have at least a power-of-2 samples or more and then process the power-of-2 number of samples from your intermediate buffer.  Rinse and repeat.

Also, newer FFTs will often allow sizes with prime factors larger than 2.

Comment: This the stop-gap solution I've been using. It introduces a bit of delay on the audio, though, due to the queuing. If I naively chained many effects together that would add up.

Comment: You might try testing using a smaller power-of-2 to see if that works and helps with latency.

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation requires that you have a power of 2 sample size, then you can pad the sample to force it to accept. Zero padding seems to be the easiest/most straight forward.

Here is an article that explains another way to do it:

**[The Chirp z-Transform Algorithm and Its Application](http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol48-1969/articles/bstj48-5-1249.pdf)**

Comment: That won't introduce artefacts in the output of the FFT that ultimately cause 'bad' audio after making changes in frequency space and transforming back?

Comment: Any padding is going to introduce some noise into the FFT. If you only have an implementation that accepts power of 2 sample size though I don't know of any other option.

Comment: @Strilanc : If you plan on making changes in the frequency domain, then you may have to zero-pad.  It's part of the overlap-add/save fast convolution filtering process.